# Custom function to create an index of results

Tags: function, r, if-statement

I’m trying to create a function which creates an index (starting at 100) and then adjust this index according to the results of investments. So, in a nutshell, if the first investment gives an profit of 5%, then the index will stand 105, if the second result is -7%, then the index stands at 97.65. In this question when I use the word "index", I'm *not* referring to the `index` function of the `zoo` package.

Besides creating this index, my **goal** is also to create an function which can be applied to various subsets of my complete data set (i.e. with the use of `sapply` and it's friends).

Here’s the function which I have so far (data at end of this question):

```
CalculateIndex <- function(x){
    totalAccount <- accountValueStart
    if(x$TradeResult.Currency == head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)){
        indexedValues <- 100 + ( 100 *((((x$Size.Units. * x$EntryPrice) / totalAccount) * x$TradeResult.Percent.) / 100))
        # Update the accountvalue
        totalAccount <- totalAccount + x$TradeResult.Currency.
    }   
    else{ # the value is not the first
        indexedValues <- c(indexedValues, 
                indexedValues[-1] + (indexedValues[-1] *(((x$Size.Units. * x$EntryPrice) / totalAccount) * x$TradeResult.Percent.) / 100)
                )
            # Update the accountvalue
            totalAccount <- totalAccount + x$TradeResult.Currency.      
    }
    return(indexedValues)
}
```

In words the function does (read: is intended to do) the following:
*If the value is the first, use `100` as an starting point for the index. If the value is not the first, use the previous calculated index value as the starting point for calculating the new index value.* Besides this, the function also takes the weight of the individual result (compared with the `totalAccount` value) into account.

**The problem:**
Using this `CalculateIndex` function on the `theData` data frame gives the following incorrect output:

```
> CalculateIndex(theData)
 [1]  99.97901  99.94180  99.65632 101.88689 100.89309  98.92878 102.02911 100.49159  98.52955 102.02243  98.43655 100.76502  99.34869 100.76401 101.18014  99.75136  97.90130
[18] 100.39935  99.81311 101.34961
Warning message:
In if (x$TradeResult.Currency == head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

**Edit:**
Wow, I already got an vote down, though I thought my question was already too long. Sorry, I thought/think the problem lay inside my loop, so I didn't want to bore you with the details, which I thought would only give less answers. Sorry, misjudgement on my part.

The problem is, with the above output from `CalculateIndex`, that the results are wildly different from Excel. Even though this could be resulting from rounding errors (as Joris mentions below), I doubt it. In comparison with the Excel results, the R results differ quite some:

```
R output    Excel calculate values  
99,9790085700   99,97900857 
99,9418035700   99,92081189 
99,6563228600   99,57713687 
101,8868850000  101,4639947 
100,8930864300  102,3570786 
98,9287771400   101,2858564 
102,0291071400  103,3149664 
100,4915864300  103,806556  
98,5295542900   102,3361186 
102,0224285700  104,3585552 
98,4365550000   102,795089  
100,7650171400  103,5601228 
99,3486857100   102,9087897 
100,7640057100  103,6728077 
101,1801400000  104,8529634 
99,7513600000   104,6043164 
97,9013000000   102,5055298 
100,3993485700  102,9048999 
99,8131085700   102,7179995 
101,3496071400  104,0676555
```

I think it would be fair to say that the difference in output isn't the result of R versus Excel problems, but more an error in my function. So, let's focus on the function.

**The manual calculation of the function**
The function uses different variables:

- `Size.Units.`; this is the number of units which are bought at the `EntryPrice`.
- `EntryPrice`: the price at which the stocks are bought,
- `TradeResult.Percent.`: the percentage gain or loss resulting from the investment,
- `TradeResult.Currency.`: the currency value ($) of the gain or loss resulting from the investment,

These variables are used in the following section of the function:

```
100 + ( 100 *((((x$Size.Units. * x$EntryPrice) / totalAccount) * x$TradeResult.Percent.) / 100))
```

and

```
indexedValues[-1] + (indexedValues[-1] *(((x$Size.Units. * x$EntryPrice) / totalAccount) * x$TradeResult.Percent.) / 100)
```

Both of the formula's are essentially the same, with the difference that the the first starts at `100`, and the second uses the `previous value` to calculate the new indexed value.

The formula can be broken down in different steps:

First, `x$Size.Units. * x$EntryPrice` determines the **total position** that was taken, in the sense that buying 100 shares at an price of 48.98 gives an position of $4898.

The resulting **total position** is then divided by the total account size (i.e. `totalAccount`). This is needed to correct the impact of one position relative to the complete portfolio. For example, if our 100 shares bought at 48.98 drop 10 percent, the calculated index (i.e. the `CalculateIndex` function) **doesn't** have to drop 10%, because off course not all the money in `totalAccount` is invested in one stock. So, by dividing the **total position** by the `totalAccount` we get an ratio which tells us how much money is invested. For example, the position with the size of 4898 dollar (on a total account of 14000) results in a *total account loss* of 3.49% if the stock drops 10%. (i.e. `4898 / 14000 = 0.349857. 0.349857 * 10% = 3.49857%`)

This ratio (of invested amount versus total amount) is then in the formula multiplied with `x$TradeResult.Percent.`, so to get the percentage impact on the **total account** (see calculation example in the previous paragraph).

As an last step, the percentage loss on the **total account** is applied to the index value (which starts at `100`). In this case, the first investment in 100 shares bought at 48.89 dollar let's the index drop from it starting point at 100 to 99.97901, reflecting the losing trade's impact on the total account.

**End of Edit**

Stripping the function clean and then adding a part of the formula at a time, so to uncover the error, I came to the following step where the error seems to reside:

```
CalculateIndex <- function(x){
    totalAccount <- accountValueStart
    if(x$TradeResult.Currency == head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)){
        indexedValues <- totalAccount
        # Update the accountvalue
        totalAccount <- totalAccount + x$TradeResult.Currency.
    }   
    else{ # the value is not the first
        indexedValues <- c(indexedValues, totalAccount)         
            # Update the accountvalue
            totalAccount <- totalAccount + x$TradeResult.Currency.      
    }
    return(indexedValues)
}
> CalculateIndex(theData)
[1] 14000
Warning message:
In if (x$TradeResult.Currency == head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So, it seems that if I just use the `totalAccount` variable, the function doesn’t get updated correctly. This seems to suggest there is some error with the basics of the `if else` statement, because it only outputs the first value.

If I remove the `else` statement from the function, I do get values for each of the rows in `theData`. However, these are then wrongly calculated. So, it seems to me that there is some error in how this function updates the `totalAccount` variable. I don’t see where I made an error, so any suggestion would be highly appreciated. What am I doing wrong?

---

The Data

Here’s what my data looks like:

```
> theData
   Size.Units. EntryPrice TradeResult.Percent. TradeResult.Currency.
1          100      48.98                -0.06                    -3
11         100      32.59                -0.25                    -8
12         100      32.51                -1.48                   -48
2          100      49.01                 5.39                   264
13         100      32.99                 3.79                   125
14         100      34.24                -4.38                  -150
3          100      51.65                 5.50                   284
4          100      48.81                 1.41                    69
15         100      35.74                -5.76                  -206
5          100      49.50                 5.72                   283
6          100      46.67                -4.69                  -219
16         100      33.68                 3.18                   107
7          100      44.48                -2.05                   -91
17         100      32.61                 3.28                   107
8          100      45.39                 3.64                   165
9          100      47.04                -0.74                   -35
10         100      47.39                -6.20                  -294
18         100      33.68                 1.66                    56
19         100      33.12                -0.79                   -26
20         100      32.86                 5.75                   189

theData <- structure(list(X = c(1L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 15L, 
    5L, 6L, 16L, 7L, 17L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 18L, 19L, 20L), Size.Units. = c(100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), EntryPrice = c(48.98, 
    32.59, 32.51, 49.01, 32.99, 34.24, 51.65, 48.81, 35.74, 49.5, 
    46.67, 33.68, 44.48, 32.61, 45.39, 47.04, 47.39, 33.68, 33.12, 
    32.86), TradeResult.Percent. = c(-0.06, -0.25, -1.48, 5.39, 3.79, 
    -4.38, 5.5, 1.41, -5.76, 5.72, -4.69, 3.18, -2.05, 3.28, 3.64, 
    -0.74, -6.2, 1.66, -0.79, 5.75), TradeResult.Currency. = c(-3L, 
    -8L, -48L, 264L, 125L, -150L, 284L, 69L, -206L, 283L, -219L, 
    107L, -91L, 107L, 165L, -35L, -294L, 56L, -26L, 189L)), .Names = c("X", 
    "Size.Units.", "EntryPrice", "TradeResult.Percent.", "TradeResult.Currency."
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

# Set the account start @ 14000
> accountValueStart <- 14000
```

Comment: @Jura25: I tried to edit your question by adding ASCII representation of your data object (with: `dput()`), to be able to read the dataframe in R more easily.

Comment: @Jura - Do you need to make sure your data is sorted properly? I'm not following all the details about your index, but the value for indexedValues[k] relies on the computed values on indexedValues[k - 1]. The data you posted above seem to indicate that the row order may not be in line..i.e. 1, 11, 12, 2, 13, 14, etc...Also, why not pass `accountStartValue` in as a second parameter to your function?

Comment: @Jura what you describe in words has very little bearing on what you've tried to code up. There is a Currency variable, some Units and Prices that you haven't described but which seem integral to what you are trying to do. Your code is very hard to read, also. Can you explain what `Size.Units.`, `EntryPrice` and `TradeResult.Currency.` are and how they enter into the problem.

Comment: @ the downvoter: there is NO reason to downvote this question. It's not because the OP made some coding errors that it is a bad question. He gives enough information on what he has, what he wants to do, and his data. How else would I've been able to solve this in 10 min?

Comment: @Gavin: It would be a nice puzzle to ask on an exam R programming: Optimize the following code :-)

Comment: @Jura : Your question wasn't exactly more clear after your edit. I took the liberty to reduce the clutter a bit. All important information is there, and I could figure out what you wanted before the edit. Just look at the solution I provided, it does what you want.

Comment: @daroczig: thanks, that is an good tip! I'll use it in future questions.

Comment: @Chase: correct, it is a time sorted data frame. Good idea to use `accountValueStart` as an second parameter, hadn't thought about that. Thanks!

Comment: @Gavin: You're right, I should have provided more information. I made the bad judgement that it was just a loop problem, so that all the other info was extra clutter. I'll take your suggestion at heart with future questions.

Comment: @Joris: thanks for cleaning it up, there was indeed quite a bit clutter. Something to think about more in advance when asking a question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code looks very strange, and it seems you have a lot of misconceptions about R that come from another programming language. Gavin and Gillespie pointed out already why you get the warniong. Let me add some tips for far more optimal coding:

- [-1] does NOT mean: drop the last one. It means "keep everything but the first value", which also explains why you get erroneous results.
- calculate common things in the beginning, to unclutter your code.
- `head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)` is the same as `x$TradeResult.Currency.[1]`.
- Keep an eye on your vectors. Most of the mistakes in your code come from forgetting you're working with vectors.
- If you need a value to be the first in a vector, put that OUTSIDE of any loop you'd use, never add an if-clause in the function.
- **predefine** your vectors/matrices as much as possible, that goes a lot faster and gives less memory headaches when working with big data.
- **vectorization, vectorization, vectorization**. Did I mention **vectorization**?
- Learn the use of `debug()`, `debugonce()` and `browser()` to check what your function is doing. Many of your problems could have been solved by checking the objects when manipulated within the function.

This said and taken into account, your function becomes :

```
CalculateIndex <- function(x,accountValueStart){
  # predifine your vector
  indexedValues <- vector("numeric",nrow(x))
  # get your totalAccount calculated FAST. This is a VECTOR!!!
  totalAccount <- cumsum(c(accountValueStart,x$TradeResult.Currency.))
  #adjust length:
  totalAccount <- totalAccount[-(nrow(x)+1)]

  # only once this calculation. This is a VECTOR!!!!
  totRatio <- 1+(((x$Size.Units. * x$EntryPrice)/totalAccount) *
                 x$TradeResult.Percent.)/100

  # and now the calculations
  indexedValues[1] <- 100 * totRatio[1]
  for(i in 2:nrow(x)){
      indexedValues[i] <- indexedValues[i-1]*totRatio[i]
  }
  return(indexedValues)
}
```

and returns

```
> CalculateIndex(theData,14000)
[1]  99.97901  99.92081  99.57714 101.46399 102.35708 101.28586 103.31497 
 103.80656 102.33612 104.35856 102.79509 103.56012
[13] 102.90879 103.67281 104.85296 104.60432 102.50553 102.90490 102.71800 
 104.06766
```

So now you do:

```
 invisible(replicate(10,print("I will never forget about vectorization any more!")))
```

Comment: Thanks Joris, this works exactly as intended. Besides that, I'm grateful for the coding tips and ideas where my knowledge of R is (seriously) lacking. I've printed them so I won't repeat them. ;) haha, thanks again!

Comment: +1 for the effort of reading and going thru a long question and offering detailed tips!

Comment: +1 I step out for a lunchtime seminar and you go and provide a nice solution that is effectively what I had (but subtly different) before I went off to be educated! Damn this academic life; it interrupts SO-answering so...

Comment: @Gavin : don't worry, it's just one extra day it'll take you to overtake me in the top users list ;-)

Comment: @Joris enjoy the respite, I still have you in my sights ;-)

Comment: @Joris: Sorry to bother you again, but do you perhaps know the name of the package which can be used to summarize this function over a dataset (like `tapply`)? The `plyr` package and the basic function give me once again those dreaded vector error messages.

Comment: @Jura25 : use the function `by()`

Comment: @Joris: Excellent! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 4):

The warning message is coming from this line:

```
if(x$TradeResult.Currency == head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)){
```

It is easy to see why; `x$TradeResult.Currency` is a *vector* and thus the comparison with `head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)` yields a *vector* of logicals. (By the way, why not `x$TradeResult.Currency[1]` instead of the `head()` call?). `if()` requires a single logical not a vector of logicals, and that is what the warning is about. `ifelse()` is useful if you want to do one of two things depending upon a condition that gives a vector of logicals.

In effect, what you are doing is only entering the `if()` part of the statement and it gets executed once only, because the first element of `x$TradeResult.Currency == head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)` is `TRUE` and R ignores the others.

```
> if(c(TRUE, FALSE)) {
+ print("Hi")
+ } else {
+ print("Bye")
+ }
[1] "Hi"
Warning message:
In if (c(TRUE, FALSE)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), print("Hi"), print("Bye"))
[1] "Hi"
[1] "Bye"
[1] "Hi"  "Bye"
```

As to solving your real problem:

```
CalculateIndex2 <- function(x, value, start = 100) {
    rowSeq <- seq_len(NROW(x))
    totalAc <- cumsum(c(value, x$TradeResult.Currency.))[rowSeq]
    idx <- numeric(length = nrow(x))
    interm <- (((x$Size.Units. * x$EntryPrice) / totalAc) *
               x$TradeResult.Percent.) / 100
    for(i in rowSeq) {
        idx[i] <- start + (start * interm[i])
        start <- idx[i]
    }
    idx
}
```

which when used on `theData` gives:

```
> CalculateIndex2(theData, 14000)
 [1]  99.97901  99.92081  99.57714 101.46399 102.35708 101.28586 103.31497
 [8] 103.80656 102.33612 104.35856 102.79509 103.56012 102.90879 103.67281
[15] 104.85296 104.60432 102.50553 102.90490 102.71800 104.06766
```

What you want is a recursive function (IIRC); the current index is some function of the previous index. These are hard to solve in a vectorised way in R, hence the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gavin. Quite an basic error with vectors I would say, so thanks for your example, that made it clearer.

Comment: @Jura25 I've added a solution that I was working on before I had to leave for a seminar. In the meantime, I see @Joris Meys has beaten me to it with an answer along the same lines. The key feature of both is that we vectorise as much as possible and only do the recursive bit where we have to.

Comment: nice pointer to recursive. @Jura, you might want to check that out. Recursiveness and R, a very fun combination.

Comment: Great answer Gavin, looks quite complex but I can follow what you're doing here in this function (in hindsight it looks a lot easier ;) ). Could the recursive function also be the reason why summarizing functions don't seem to work?

Comment: [I can't edit my comment directly above this one, but I succeeded in summarizing with the functions, so that question is irrelevant now.]

Answer (score 2):

I'm still slightly confused as to what exactly you want to do, but hopefully the following will be helpful.

Your R script gives the same answers as your Excel function for the first value. You see a difference because R doesn't print out all digits.

```
> tmp = CalculateIndex(thedata)
Warning message:
In if (x$TradeResult.Currency == head(x$TradeResult.Currency., n = 1)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> print(tmp, digits=10)
 [1]  99.97900857  99.94180357  99.65632286 101.88688500 100.89308643
 <snip>
```

The reason for the warning message is because `x$TradeResult.Currency` is a vector that is being compared to a single number.

That warning message is also where your bug lives. In your `if` statement, you **never** execute the else part, since only the value of `x$TradeResult.Currency` is being used. As the warning message states, only the first element of `x$TradeResult.Currency` is being used.

Comment: @Joris-Meys: I see that from your (very nice) answer.

Comment: Thanks Csgillespie, you're right about the vectors. Sadly there was a lot more wrong with my function. ;) Thanks nonetheless for responding!